# Getting blank response from server in Android app

Tags: php, android

I am working on an Android app.

I have a method in a fragment to get a value from a remote server:

```
public void checkStatusUser()
{

    SharedPreferences prefs1 =
            getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MISDATOS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, URL_CHECK,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                    Log.d("respuests","respuesta estado user respuesta"+response.toString());  <-blank response here


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }){


        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){

            SharedPreferences prefsMisDatos =
                    getActivity().getSharedPreferences(ALERTA, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


            String dos1 = prefsMisDatos.getString("id_usuario", "por_defecto@email.com");

            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("usuario",dos1);

            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);



}
```

The response is blank.

But checking the remote file in the browser, the echoed value is ok.

I don´t know what is wrong at the Android part.
This is the PHP part:

```
<?php
    require_once('dbconnect.php');


    $uno = $_GET['usuario'];

function get_estado($uno){



    $loop = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$uno."'")
    or die (mysqli_error($dbh));


    while ($row_usua = mysqli_fetch_array($loop))
    {

        $estado_del_usuario = $row_usua['activo'];
    }
    return $estado_del_usuario;

}
echo get_estado($uno);

?>
```

Comment: Your PHP code is **vulnerable** to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: @Jeffrey; I know, thank you. I will clean it later, first I want to solve the current issue,

Comment: `echo get_estado($uno);` Change to `echo ("uno: " . $uno);` for a test. First see if your parameters come over.

Comment: Could you put your URL request directly into your browser and see what happens?